# Bootstrap Modal carousel in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm working on project on Ruby on Rails 6 and trying to make modal carousel with bootstrap 4. It works fine with the first element of massive, but don't with other elements. Arrows right and left don't work

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <% @division.galleries.each do |gallery| %>
      <div class="col">
        <%= link_to image_tag(gallery.image_url(:thumb).to_s), [gallery.division, gallery],
            data: {toggle: 'modal', target: "#myModal-#{dom_id(gallery)}"}, id: "image-#{dom_id(gallery)}" %>
        <p>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-<%= dom_id(gallery) %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <%= image_tag @division.galleries.find(gallery.id).image_url.to_s, class: "gallery1" %>
                  </div>
                  <% @division.galleries.drop(1).each do |gallery| %>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <%= image_tag gallery.image_url.to_s, class: "gallery1" %>
                    </div>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import 'bootstrap'
import './stylesheets/application'
```

Comment: Hi there, how did you enable bootstrap in your project? Did you add it via webpacker (`yarn add` or `npm install`?) or did you use the cdn?

Comment: yes, i use webpacker

Comment: Do you have the `javascript_pack_tag` enabled in your `application.html`?

Comment: Yes, bootstrap works, and i can use modal or carousel, but carousel works only with the first element

Comment: That's why I assume the javascript is the problem - because it relys on bootstrap's javascript. Do you have an error in the console in the browser?

Comment: no, there are no any errors in consol

Comment: Ok, could you also post your `application.html.erb` as well as `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

Comment: I think something wrong with my ruby code